# What is the degree of y in sin y?

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to find out the degree of the variable operated in a trigonometric or logarithmic or an exponential function? Asking out of curiosity!

Comment: What do you mean by degree?

Comment: would you be able to provide an example??

Comment: Like degree of x in x^2 is 2. But that's a polynomial function. Is it possible to find it in any other kinds of functions?

Comment: Not really, no. Degree is mostly a polynomial thing. You can ask about the degree of a zero of a function, though. The zeroes of $\sin(x)$ have degree $1$ (because they look like the zero of $x$ in a certain strictly defined sense), and the zeroes of $\sin(x)+1$ have degree $2$ (because they look like the zero of $x^2$). Unless that was "order", not degree?

Comment: The sine is a transcendental function. Degrees are usually related to polynomials, the sine is not such a polynomial.

Comment: The tag differential-equations is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The degree is defined for non-negative integer powers of the variable (monomials) and for polynomials.

It is not defined for other functions.

Rational fractions (ratio of polynomials) can be considered to have a pair of degrees, and fractional polynomials (with non-integer powers) can be considered to have a non-integer degree, but I am not sure this is standard usage.

Comment: Rational functions can also be said to have a single, possibly negative, degree. It dictates how the function behaves for large $x$ the save way it does for polynomials.

Comment: @Arthur: yes but a piece of information is lost.